# success message after adding a product in Magentowith Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, magento, message

I know trough Firebug Json is generating a message after the    success: function    but can´t find how to show it... so I tried adding this:

```
if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                        jQuery("#ajax_message").html("product out of stock.").hide().fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
                    }else{if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){
                             jQuery("#ajax_message").html("product added.").hide().fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
                        }
```

But nothing come to light after the product has been added..

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the response you are getting in data.status

Check if confilct is there.Use noConflict.
.hide would hide the div

Hope you solved it :)

Comment: YEs I already checked all of these above and nothing was wrong, perhaps    hide will hide the    div just until the function is triggered